# Where to publish articles about open source?

Tags: open-source, articles, publications

I've been developing a free, open source Java database abstraction project ([jOOQ](http://jooq.sourceforge.net)) and I have released first stable releases from November 2010 onwards. Feedback has been quite good and constructive, and I am very motivated to continue my work.

In the mean time, to get more attention and feedback, I have published articles on

- http://java.dzone.com/
- http://www.theserverside.com/
- http://www.infoq.com/ (they didn't publish my article, though)

These are some sample articles so you know the type of article I want to publish:

- http://java.dzone.com/announcements/simple-and-intuitive-approach
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/2011-great-year-stored

What other resources would you recommend? Where else should I publish, knowing that

- I want to reach Java/SQL developers and architects / technology decision makers
- I can publish in English, German, French
- I think that my project is suitable for both beginners and pro's (in Java and SQL, or programming in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ - [IBM Developerworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DeveloperWorks)

> a free web-based professional network and technical resource center from IBM for software developers, IT professionals, and students worldwide. The site attracts 4 million unique visitors per month in 195 countries, and is designed to help users develop and master skills, solve problems, collaborate with peers, and stay ahead of the latest trends in open standards...

Comment: Right. That one should clearly be on the list

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look for forums that are more specialized towards databases.  The choice of which database to use is oftentimes an executive level decision and is not likely to change without a good reason.

You need to find where these people go and what they read when they are looking at changing what they will trust with all of their data.

[Database Journal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/)

You'll also want to try to get in with forums read by executives, like Forrester Research, if possible.

Comment: That's good input, I hadn't thought of that yet. I was only focusing on the J2EE-folks, but obviously it's all about databases as well